# Combining formula to get unqiue list from delimited values in a column with formula to get range concatenating Sheet-name to output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have cell values in a column that can be piped delimited ex: `DR|Border|Yaque del Norte` or empty or non-delimited ex: `Cat`

I have a formula that gets the unique list of all values (delimited on not) from a column

`=SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN("|",Elements!A2:A),"|"))))))`

From the three values above I would get

```
Border
Cat
DR
Yaque
```

I have a formula that gets the range `Elements!A2:A`

`indirect("Elements!"&substitute(address(1,match(A1,Elements!1:1,0),4),"1","")&"2:"&substitute(address(1,match(A1,Elements!1:1,0),4),"1",""))`

But when I do this my output becomes

```
Elements!Border
Cat
Elements!DR
Elements!Yaque
```

All the delimited elements have `Elements!` added to them

How to prevent this

Thanks

Google sheet with data and formulas
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15tpuRdZUrSfiNapXWUtL2Zt1QOaxtf4T7SG1FwLyi30/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `offset()` function, like this:

```
=sort( unique( transpose( trim( 
  split( 
    join( 
      "|", 
      offset( Elements!A2:A, 0, match(A1, Elements!A1:D1, 0) - 1 ) 
    ), 
    "|", false, true 
  ) 
) ) ) )
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15tpuRdZUrSfiNapXWUtL2Zt1QOaxtf4T7SG1FwLyi30/edit#gid=1190329791), cell `H2` in the "ignore" sheet.